# error propagation of a quantity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I have $e =$ 0.015 $\pm$ 0.005.

How would I use error of propagation to calculate the uncertainty on

$$ \frac{1}{( 1 - e^2)^{\frac{1}{8}} } $$

### **EDIT**

Since the question was put on **hold** then I will give all the details.

I have the following formula that I am interested to calculate the quantity and the uncertainty

$$ T_{eq} = T_{eff} \sqrt{\frac{R_*}{2a}} \frac{1}{(1-e^2)^{\frac{1}{8}}}$$

For simplification, $T_{eq} = ABC$.

where $A = T_{eff}$, B$ =  \sqrt{\frac{R_*}{2a}}$, and $C = \frac{1}{(1-e^2)^{\frac{1}{8}}}$

Let $\delta(T_{eff})$ be the uncertainty on $T_{eff}$

$$ \delta(T_{eff}) = |ABC| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\delta A}{A} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\delta B}{B} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\delta C}{C} \right)^2}$$

Having well defined the problem, now I have to calculate the quantities in the radical:

1. $A = T_{eff}$ (given)
2. $\delta A = \delta T_{eff} $ (given)
3. $ B = \sqrt{\frac{R_*}{2a}} = x^{0.5}$
4. Following think [link](http://physics.appstate.edu/undergraduate-programs/laboratory/resources/error-propagation), $B$ is given in an exponent form. Hence

   $$ \frac{\delta B}{B} = 0.5 \times \frac{\delta x}{|x|}$$

   $$\delta x = \delta \left( \frac{R_*}{2a} \right) = \frac{R_*}{2a} \sqrt{\left( \frac{\delta R_*}{R_*} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\delta a}{a} \right)^2} $$
5. $C = \frac{1}{(1-e^2)^{\frac{1}{8}}}$
6. $\delta C = \frac{\partial C}{\partial e} \sigma_e$

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial e} \sigma_e = \frac{e/4 (1-e^2)^{-7/8}}{(1-e^2)^{2/8}} \sigma_e
= \frac{e}{4}{(1-e^2)^{-9/8}} \sigma_e$$

Is this correct?

For  $T_{eff} = 5777 \pm 61$

$R_* = (1.23 \times 0.0046491) \pm 0.01 $

$ a = 0.229 \pm 0.001$

and $e = 0.0684 \pm 0.0002$

I get, $T_{eq} = 645.137 \pm 564.132 $

That's a HUGE value on the uncertainty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: apply your formulas - if need be, do it step by step. What's the error of e^2? What's the error of $(1-e^2)$, what's the error of $(1-e^2)^{1/8}$, etc.

Comment: @Martin, the error of $(1-e^2)$ is the same as the error of $e^2$, right?

Comment: Define $f\left( e \right) \equiv \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 - {e^2}} \right)}^{1/8}}}}$. Then the error in f is ${\sigma _f} = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial e}}{\sigma _e}$.

Comment: @Jake, can you check the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin, is the question still on hold? If yes, can you please tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: First, this is error-propagation, so strictly speaking, it's more maths than physics. Second, this is not a conceptual question. It's about applying formulae to your specific example. Third, this is "check-my-work-question". The question is off-topic for any one of the reasons. Have a look at meta for more reasons, but one reason is that such questions are only interesting to you personally and very uninteresting to others. Another is that they are usually answered in a discussion - but this is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e$ is small you can use a binomial expansion:

$$ \left(1 - e^2\right)^{-1/8} = 1 + \tfrac{1}{8}e^2 + O(e^4) $$

Ignore the $e^4$ terms and higher, and you have the much simpler task of calculating the error in the expression $1 + \tfrac{1}{8}e^2$.

Comment: $\delta(1+\frac{1}{8}e^2) = \delta(\frac{1}{8}e^2) = \frac{1}{8}\delta(e^2) = \frac{1}{8} 2e\delta(e)$. Right? @John

Comment: @po6: careful, you're mixing up percentage errors and absolute errors. The absolute error in $1+\tfrac{1}{8}e^2$ is $\tfrac{1}{8}$ the absolute error in $e^2$. However it's the percentage error in $e^2$ that is twice the percentage error in $e$. Write the expression as $1+\tfrac{1}{8}(e+\Delta e)^2$, expand it out and discard terms of order $\Delta e^2$ and you should get a nice simple result.

Comment: can you please see the detailed explanation. I edited the question.